# Передача строки cp1251 через ajax в php обработчик

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Здравствуйте уважаемы форумчане.
Сайт имеет кодировку cp1251.
Переменная `$catalogVars['goodsName']` является строкой.

```
function set_cart(){
var value = "{$catalogVars['goodsName']}";
var cart_array =  { "price" :{$catalogVars['goodsPrice']}, "article" :{$catalogVars['goodsArticle']}, "value" :value };
jQuery.ajax({
        url:'http:cart.php'
      , type:'POST'
      , data:'a=' +JSON.stringify(cart_array)
      , success: function(response) {
       document.write(response);
     }
  });

}
```

В обработчике `var_dump($_POST);`
Строка превращается `РЈРјРµР№ РґРµР№СЃС‚РІРѕРІР°С‚СЊ РїСЂРё РїРѕР¶Р°СЂРµ`
Как вариант можно использовать base64encode - но не перебор ли это?

Comment: JS в принципе имеет дело только с UTF8. Вне зависимости от кодировки сайта все содержимое переменных JS (в том числе и передаваемые через ajax) в UTF8. И даже если вы выполните base64encode на стороне клиента внутри будут строки в UTF8. Вам придется использовать mb_convert_encoding на стороне сервера для перевода кодировок

Comment: Это не зашифрованная строка, а браузер не правильно читает кодировку, т.к. она либо не указана, либо указана не правильно. Смотри в сторону метода `iconv`.

Comment: Нет, насчет base64encode я имел ввиду, закодировать строку до отправки. Обработчик строку закодированную нормально определяет (правда плюсы на пробелы меняет), и на стороне обработчика ее декодировать.

Answer (score 1):

У меня была похожая проблема, только здесь я наоборот отправлял JSON. Помогла функция в php

```
function normJsonStr($str){
        $str = preg_replace_callback('/\\\u([a-f0-9]{4})/i', create_function('$m', 'return chr(hexdec($m[1])-1072+224);'), $str);
        return iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $str);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

в чем проблема поменять кодировку сайта на UTF-8? вопрос-жеж нескольких минут. и не будет ненужных функций декодирования и ненужной нагрузки.

Comment: Проблема в том, что сайт большой и старый.